How to fetch Kubernetes Pod details in AWS EKS cluster using AWS Lambda function
I am relatively new to Kubernetes world.
I have a requirement to fetch the pod details of multiple namespaces in a cluster programatically.
Currently I am trying to write a Lambda function using nodeJS.
Stuck with below error.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 8080
}
Code used :
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');
exports.handler = async (event, context) =\> {
try { // Load Kubernetes config
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();
const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
// Fetch pod details
const apiEndPoint = kc.getCurrentCluster()?.server;
console.log('K8s API server', apiEndPoint) // "Getting http://localhost:8080" as responsse"
const response = await k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('kube-system');
return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(response) };
}
catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching pod details:', error);
return { statusCode: 500, body: JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), };
 }
 };

Note: Lambda role has below policies attached
AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
Also Lambda is configured in same VPC as EKS.
Can I get some help to understand what am I missing here ?

Please explain why you need it in JS and run it in Lambda? Is it a requirement or your preference?

the lambda isn't part of the k8s cluster

@Covik Its my preference  to use Lambda and JS, but to fetch it programatically is an requirement.

The issue is that you didn't configure the lambda to check for cluster on the correct location. This happens because kc.loadFromDefault() tries to look for kubernetes on the local host, like it's stating in the error: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 8080 . and the Lambda doesn't have any kubernetes API server locally.
So the default configuration looks for Kubernetes locally, unless you overwritten it.
As a resume: your Lambda needs to be explicitly configured to locate the Kubernetes API server in the EKS cluster. so instead of using kc.loadFromDefault(), you should configure the Kubernetes client to authenticate using the IAM role attached to the Lambda and use kc.loadFromCluster(). This ensures that the Lambda can communicate with the EKS cluster without needing kubeconfig files.
you can find an example here: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/in-cluster.js
Or you can load from a configuration that you create will all your cluster details as stating here (check the Create a cluster configuration programatically part):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kubernetes/client-node
The lambda function need to be in the same VPC and subnet as the EKS, and The EKS cluster’s control plane security group must allow traffic from the Lambda’s security group to port 443.
lastly, you need to ensure the Lambda IAM role has the necessary permissions for Kubernetes RBAC.

Thanks @Fedi Bounouh, for taking your time to explain on this. With the suggested changes, I am currently seeing "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt' " error. Probably I am missing the last part of RBAC. Would you mind sharing some resource which helps on that ?

https://jvlewis.dev/how-to-authenticate-to-aws-eks-api-server-from-lambda-python-c2b0510cc009 : this medium article is talking about the authentication, but it's using python instead of ts. but it remains helpful for you to understand the RBAC part.
